# How to find the number of pages which has one method of drawing?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, prime-numbers, arithmetic, divisibility

The problem is as follows:

> Jenny bought a manga drawing book to her daughter so she could learn
> the technique for her further animation studies. The book has 720
> pages so it can be colored with pencils.
>
> However she noticed the following:
>
> On the pages whose numbering is even and that exactly divides the
> total of pages, her daughter used the stitching technique.
>
> On the pages whose numbering is a multiple of 3 and which divides
> exactly to the total number of pages, her daugther has used the
> outline technique.
>
> On those pages whose numbering is a multiple of 5 and divisor of 720
> she used the shading technique.
>
> Using the information found by Jenny's. Find the number of pages which
> her daughter has used only one painting technique.

The alternatives given in my book are as follows:

$\begin{array}{ll}
1.&\textrm{4}\\
2.&\textrm{5}\\
3.&\textrm{7}\\
4.&\textrm{6}\\
\end{array}$

The official solution from my book states the following:

Please note that I'm requiring some help here because the concept it is not very clear.

The approach that my book uses is:

$\operatorname{factor}(720)=2^4\cdot 3^2 \cdot 5$

Then it goes to count all the divisors which are multiples of

$2$, $3$, $5$, $6$ and $30$.

I don't know why **those specific numbers**, my best guess was that those are resulting from multiplying all the combinations from 2, 3 and 5.

Interestingly the qunatity of divisors of $720$ is $30$. **But does this has anything to do with the prior selection of those numbers?**

Anyways it goes as follows: (The notation $QD_{n}$ denotes the quantity of divisors of that number multiples of $n$).

$\operatorname{QD}_{2}(720)=4\times 3 \times 2 = 24$

This comes from the factorization: $720= 2\times(2^3\cdot 3^2 \cdot 5)$

$\operatorname{QD}_{3}(720)=(4+1)(1+1)(1+1)=20$

This comes from the factorization: $720= 3\times(2^4\cdot 3^1 \cdot 5)$

$\operatorname{QD}_{5}(720)=(4+1)(2+1)=15$

This comes from the factorization: $720= 5\times(2^4\cdot 3^2)$

$\operatorname{QD}_{6}(720)=(3+1)(1+1)(1+1)=16$

This comes from the factorization: $720= 6\times(2^3\cdot 3^1 \cdot 5)$

$\operatorname{QD}_{10}(720)=(3+1)(2+1)=12$

This comes from the factorization: $720= 10\times(2^3\cdot 3^2)$

$\operatorname{QD}_{30}(720)=(3+1)(1+1)=8$

This comes from the factorization: $720= 30\times(2^3\cdot 3^1)$

Well after doing all of that my book concludes that the number of pages on which it was used only one technique is:

$4+2+1=7$

But I don't know where does it come those numbers?. They seem to be the same powers of the prime factorization from $720$.

But it lacks from a proper explanation **why should those numbers be the total of pages on which only one drawing technique was used?**

**Perhaps does it exist a way to reverse engineering what was intended to be done here or something like that?.**

I'm trying to get the idea but I'm lost, hence I need for asistance. Can someone help me with a step by step explanation on which sort of method using divisors could be used to find those pages where it was used only one technique?.

So far the only idea which I have is that such number of pages must be let's say multiple of $2$, but not multiple of $3$ or $5$. Is this right?. Please help me here as I'm lost.

Comment: Did the book not also consider  $\operatorname{QD}_{10}(720)$?

Comment: Google "inclusion and exclusion".

Comment: This problem can be asked with $25\%$ of the above words, and will garner more assistance that way.

Comment: @saulspatz Sorry for the late reply but you're absolutely right. It was mentioned in the official solution. But as I mentioned I am confused exactly why those numbers in particular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every divisor of $720$ is of the form $2^r3^s5^t$ for some $r,s,t$. We can say more: $0\le r\le4$, $0\le s\le2$, $0\le t\le1$.

Now the ones that are multiples of $2$ but of neither $3$ nor $5$ are just the ones of the form $2^r$, $1\le r\le 4$, and there are four of them.

The ones that are multiples of $3$ but of neither $2$ nor $5$ are just the ones of the form $3^s$, $1\le s\le 2$, and there are two of them.

The ones that are multiples of $5$ but of neither $2$ nor $3$ are just the ones of the form $5^t$, $1\le t\le 1$, and there is just one of them.

So the total number is $4+2+1=7$.

And it's exactly as you said – these numbers are coming from the exponents $4,2,1$ in the factorization $720=2^43^25^1$.

Comment: So when you say the ones which are multiples of $2$ these are $2^1$ ,$2^2$, $2^3$ and $2^4$, am I right with this? The same logic goes for the ones which are multiples of $3$ and for $5$ right?. Okay I get this idea. But why bothering to compute all the quantity of divisors for $2$, $3$, $5$, $6$, $10$ and $30$?. Was this done on purpose or what?. To me it seems that it was unnecesary. Or it was not? Can you explain me what it was intended?.

Comment: Saulspatz mentioned in the comments from above that this has to do with inclusion exclusion. Which I happen to read [on this entry in wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) I get the idea that this counting technique avoids counting twice elements satisfying at least one property. But in this case it constrains the counting for just multiples of three, two and five. The principle uses sets as examples and subtracts from a union the intersection. In the case of multiplication, it means not counting the other multiples. Is this the logic?

Comment: I'm accepting your answer but I'd really appreciate if you could on my request to include the answers to my above comments as part of your answer because *that way would help me better to understand why it was neded to count all the combinations from those divisors*. Maybe was just for justification of using the sum of the powers?.

Comment: I don't think it was necessary to do anything more than what I did. I don't know why your source did all those other calculations. Maybe they're needed for some subsequent investigation? Inclusion-exclusion is a very useful counting technique, and sometimes it's the only way to get an answer, but as I say for this particular problem I don't think anything was needed beyond what I wrote.